# Firefox Addon : parse/save loaded jsons as HAR or text file

Tags: json, firefox, firefox-addon, real-time

I'm trying out to build my first firefox addon, to solve a problem that I have at work :
I'm trying to automate a part of my daily work on a website I'm using (not developping). I have to crawl several lists on the website, dig an item in the list, to check some values, and do it again and again ...

Im used to developping in Powershell and python, not with a web browser. I have limited rights on the machine I'm working on. The only solution I can easily deploy is a firefox addon on a firefox portable. I'd like to use this to catch the json answers of the website (all of them), parse the answers for some values, and automate some kind of popup "Hey, This item in the list is between 90 and 100 !"

The network console allows me to see the jsons, and I know how to parse it well (I'm actually using a powershell script for this, but I can't connect it to the network console AFAIK)

I found a way to trigger the work at the right time :

```
function logJson(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Chargement : " + requestDetails.url);
}

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  logRequests,
  {urls: ["*://*.crappywebsi.te/*"],
   types: ["xmlhttprequest"]
  }
);
```

This code logs the url at the right moment (every time a json is loaded)

Is it possible to catch the json on the fly, to parse it, look for specific values in a path, calculate something, and popup the result ?
Or just save the json somewhere ?
How ?

I dont want to add a button on the webpage. I want a signal that some values are right. a popup or console log is an good solution for me.

Thanks for your help !